# Low-Dimensional Spaces with High-Dimensional Homology

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homology, counterexamples, loop-spaces

Barratt-Milnor Spheres $X_n$ are spaces with finite topological dimension $n$ but which have non-vanishing singular homology in arbitrarily high dimensions.  [Here, they prove](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034486) that if $n > 1$ then the singular homology $H_q(X_n, \mathbb{Q})$ is non-zero whenever $q \equiv 1 \mod (n-1)$.  I'm wondering the following:

1. Is there a finite-dimensional space (ideally, compact and connected) where *none* of the higher homology groups vanish?  Preferably something kind of intrinsic, rather than just gluing a bunch of Barratt-Milnor Spheres at a point.  If so, what's the minimal dimension of the space?
2. Is there an example where *some* high-dimensional homology group doesn't vanish (higher than the dimension of the space), but where homology does *eventually* stabilize to zero?  If so, what's the minimal dimension of the space?  If it's not possible, can it asymptotically stabilize to zero?

Those two are the more sophisticated questions (I assume) from a thread I've put a couple bounties on without luck on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996795/examples-of-finite-dimensional-space-with-non-vanishing-homology-in-higher-dimen

There are some additional questions there of a more didactic nature, as well.  I suppose questions 1/2 here could be extended to ask for all the higher-dimensional groups to be free, or free of bounded rank, or torsion etc.  What results are known about such constraints?

Comment: In what sense are the Barratt-Milnor spheres "finite dimensional"? I have a hard time thinking of a notion of dimension that does not bound the cohomological dimension (yes, they are a quotient of a finite dimensional space, but every compactum is a quotient of a zero-dimensional space so that does not mean much)

Comment: @DenisNardin: presumably Barrett--Milnor are talking about the topological dimension. If I have it right (I alway get this stuff confused), this gives you a natural bound on the dimensions of the nerves of open covers of the space, and hence a bound on the dimension of Cech cohomology, as Barratt--Milnor say explicitly in their article.

Comment: Regarding 1, I think it will be hard to get a good answer without being more specific about what you mean by "intrinsic". The obvious thing to do is to cross some Barratt--Milnor spheres with ordinary spheres and then wedge them together. If you don't like wedges, you could attach some further cells to make the examples more complicated...

Comment: The "Barratt-Milnor Spheres" are often called the $n$-dimensional Hawaiian earring and are denoted $\mathbb{H}_n$ (or something similar). Some progress has and is still being made on understanding the homotopy and integral homology groups of these spaces but these questions are almost certainly open as stated. However, for $k>n$, I think it's very reasonable to expect that $H_k(\mathbb{H}_n,\mathbb{Z})$ is non-trivial whenever $\pi_k(S^n)$ is non-trivial, which is a lot but not *always*.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas Note that when $k>n$ and $n=2,3,4,5$, then this is [always](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00952.pdf). But if $n>5$, then this is not always (consider $k=n+4$).

Comment: @Tyrone That's right! Thanks. In that case, I expect $\mathbb{H}_2$ to work as an example to 1. I doubt a formal proof exists.

Comment: Sorry yes, I mean topological dimension.  I was more afraid that my question would be some trivial consequence of a homework exercise in Hatcher and I'd be embarrassed, rather than the problems being open.  I expect question 2 to be false (at least the stronger ask), I think there may be some slick cohomology argument for that, it just has that feel.

Comment: Yeah about the intrinsic part, I left that vague on purpose.  I suppose one (of many) formulations would be something like: there is no decomposition of $X$ into copies of a space where this also happens (e.g. usc decomp).  You could also require that there's no contractible subspace $C \subset X$ such that $X = Y \cup Z$ where $Y \cap Z = C$ and both of $Y, Z$ satisfy the same homology/dimension properties of $X$.  That probably needs further formulation, hence the vagueness x)

Comment: Yes, this is a difficult business. After thinking about it some more, I'm less confident about my guess. Right now, I am not sure if the summand $\prod_{\mathbb{N}}\pi_k(S^n)$ of $\pi_k(\mathbb{H}_n)$ gets trivialized in $H_k(\mathbb{H}_n)$.

Comment: Milnor and Barret seems to produce elements in $\pi_{t(n-1)+1}(X_n)$ for each $t\geq1$ which have nonzero rational Hurewicz image. Does taking $n=2$ not answer your first question?

Comment: Some of the algebraic topology in that paper/your comment is a bit over my head, or at least I'm not very comfortable with it.  Can you post it as an answer with more details?  No worries if not.  Especially, translating to singular $\mathbb{Z}$-homology.

Comment: Like, they definitely prove that $H_n(\mathbb{H}_2, \mathbb{Q}) \neq 0$ for all $n > 1$, that's clear.  Is that enough to infer that $H_n(\mathbb{H}_2, \mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes. This is just the universal coefficient theorem. See Hatcher pg. 261. If I can find a nice example for your second question I'll write it up as an answer.